# Problema con upload en PHP

Tags: php, fileupload

Me surgió este problema de repente. Todo funcionaba correctamente y al reinstalar el xampp y volver a clonar el repositorio de la misma forma, me salta un error que no ocurría.

El error es el siguiente:

```
Warning: Undefined array key "image" in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\public\controller\sistema_controller.php on line 62

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\public\controller\sistema_controller.php on line 62

Warning: Undefined array key "image" in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\public\controller\sistema_controller.php on line 68

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\public\controller\sistema_controller.php on line 68
```

El código utilizado es el siguiente:

```
                        <form id="form_image" action="<?php $this->route('sistema', 'ubicacion', $this->getParam()); ?>" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name="send_location_image" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="image" class="col-lg-4 col-form-label">
                                <div class="img" style="background: url(<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>/public/assets/img/cities/<?php echo $this->params['location']['image']; ?>) no-repeat 50% 50% / cover;"></div>
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-lg-8 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-start">
                                <h6 class="mb-4">Imagen</h6>
                                <div class="upload">
                                    <input type="file" name="image">
                                    <label for="image">
                                        <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
                                        <span>Seleccionar archivo</span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

**sistema_controller.php:**

```
        if(isset($_POST['send_location_image']))
    {
        $route = 'public/assets/img/cities/';
        $file = $route . basename($ _FILES['image']['name']);
        $fileType = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(!file_exists($route))
        {
            mkdir($route, 0777);
        }
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $file))
        {
            rename($file, $route . time() . $fileType);
            $this->params['data_success'] = 'Imagen actualizada';
        }
    }
```

¿A qué se puede deber? Un saludo.

Comment: El form debe tener el argumento enctype="multipart/form-data" ,  lo tienes en el input.

Comment: Correcto, solucionado. Muchísimas gracias. ¿Podrías confirmarme porque antes me funcionaba bien? No tenía el enctype en ningún lado, eso lo metí ahora buscando info.

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El form debe tener el argumento enctype="multipart/form-data" , lo tienes en el input.  Si antes no veías los mensajes, quizás es porque tenías los Warnings apagados y al resintalar volvieron a su configuración por defecto.